# Ionic: Running APK on emulator: WebView does not exist?

Tags: ionic-framework, webview, android-emulator

**Skippable info**: I'm trying to get my first Ionic Android app running on Ubuntu without Android Studio. I'm doing everything from the command line. I have installed everything that is needed (java, node + ionic and cordova packages, gradle, Android sdk) and everything is included in my PATH variable.

**The problem**: Building the app via `ionic cordova build android` is successful, the APK gets generated. After that I start my avd via `emulator @Nexus_4_API_26`. The phone appears on my screen. Then I pull the APK into the GUI of the emulator to install it. Then I try to start the app but I get "MyApp has stopped working". I use `adb logcat` to get more info on the error and what I see is this:

```
Chromium WebView package does not exist
android.webkit.WebViewFactory$MissingWebViewPackageException: Failed to load WebView provider: No WebView installed
```

I don't know what WebView is but apparently it is needed by Ionic. What I find really odd is that I find nothing (ionic-related!) on google when I search for "ionic chromium webview package does not exist". I have created a totally normal/default Nexus avd (API 26). If anything essential was missing for Ionic in my emulator, I would expect a ton of results on google for this error. What's the problem here and why does it seem like I'm the only one affected?

Comment: I found the reason: I was using one of those system images without Google APIs. Google APIs are needed for Ionic Apps.

Comment: Actually we are trying to support ionic apps for Android devices that do not have Google APIs. and we are facing the same problem. Were you able to find a workaround?